# Paper sludge production / recycling

Tags: data-request

I'm interested in any dataset with yearly production (generation) of paper sludges, hopefully by country (even approximate figures would be ok).

Big pluses:

- Dollar (or Euro) values for disposing it
- Humidity and/or calorific value
- Recycled tons
- Wether the source is tissue or standard paper

Comment: As I don't have the required reputation to suggest new tags, I kindly ask someone who can to include "waste" and "recycling" as tags to this question.